# Tried to run pulseaudio

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, ubuntu-18.04, pulse-audio

When I was trying to do [this](https://superuser.com/a/750324/1169109) It got me an error on running `pactl list | grep Name` command.
I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with linux deploy and LXDE desktop.

Error:

```
shared memfd open() failed: Function not implemented
Connection failure: Connection refused
```